# How do I wire up a UWP App PointerReleased for a listview?

Tags: uwp

I have a listview control in a xaml page. Within its associated .cs pages constructor I have this code:

ScheduleListView.PointerReleased += LVI_PointerReleased;

The method LVI_PointerReleased is as follows:

```
    private void LVI_PointerReleased(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CardSwipe.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
    }
```

The idea is that upon the mouse up event from the listview 'ScheduleListView' the PointerReleased event is fired thereby executing the 'LVI_PointerReleased ' method. The purpose of the method is to shift focus to the textbox 'CardSwipe'. However the PointerReleased event is never fired during the mouseup event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . However the PointerReleased event is never fired during the mouseup event.

The problem is that `PointerReleased` Handled by the `ListViewItem`, it will not bubble down. You could press the empty area to verify this.

For your scenario, we suggest you add `AddHandler` to [registering handlers for already-handled routed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#registering-handlers-for-already-handled-routed-events).

```
private void MyList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyList.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(MyList_PointerReleased), true);
}

private void MyList_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   
}
```

Comment: What if you have a dynamic list of objects inside an `ItemsControl` that has no unique name in order to add the handler?